# rake db:drop and db:create do the tasks with failure

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

`rake db:drop` complains that database does not exist, but actually drops it.

`rake db:create` complains that database already exists, but actually creates it.

DBMS is MySQL. This behaviour occurs only on one machine. On other servers the same application creates and drops database without any issues.

Comment: I have seen that happen when my `config/database.yml` has `development` & `test` databases defined, and I had dropped only one of them.

Comment: @Prakash Murthy: I doesn't make any difference whether some databases exist or not - result is always the same.

Comment: @Paul can you post full output from terminal?

Answer (score 0):

When you run rake db:migrate or db:create without mentioning any environment then by default rails try to drop/create dev/test databases;
it could occur when your one of db either test or dev is not present when you are trying to drop and one of db is present when you are trying to create.

drop the both db (test/dev) and then rake db:create, it won't throw error.and after this run rake db:drop, will work fine.